# MySQL - Grouping and counting

Tags: mysql, sql

My database structure contains:

**actions**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| placement_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| lead_id      | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**placements**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| publisher_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status       | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**leads**

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| status  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to retrieve a number of statuses per each placement (groupped):

```
| placement_id | placement_name | count
+--------------+----------------+-------
| 123          | PlacementOne   | 12
| 567          | PlacementTwo   | 15
```

I tried countless times and every query I wrote seems dumb, so I won't even post them here. I'm hopeless. An well commented query (so I can learn) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select a.placement_id, p.name as placement_name, count(l.status)
from actions a
inner join placements p on p.id = a.placement_id 
inner join leads l on l.id = a.lead_id 
group by a.placement_id, p.name
```

Comment: good understand what actually OP needed without much explanation